# CDKworkshop: ImportError: No module named aws_cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aws-cdk, python-venv

I'm following the CDKworkshop.com. All good until the Advanced topic: Testing constructs -> Assertion tests. When I execute the pytest command it gives the error:

```
tests/unit/test_cdk_workshop.py:1: in <module>
from aws_cdk import (
E   ImportError: No module named aws_cdk
```

I Followed all the steps in the workshop.

Activated venv

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

installed the requirements.txt

```
aws-cdk-lib==2.37.0
constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0
cdk-dynamo-table-view==0.2.0
```

installed the requirements-dev.txt

```
pytest==6.2.5
```

Expected output from running pytest command:

```
$ pytest
===============session starts =======================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ...
collected 1 item

tests/unit/test_cdk_workshop.py .                                                                                                                                                                               [100%]

======================================================================
```

Comment: Are you running your `pytest` from the right terminal (the one where your venv is activated)?

Comment: Yes, am using the same terminal in WSL as for the other the other assignments